# Why can't you query database paths/files using REST?

Tags: basex

I have a database like so

```
<rest:databases xmlns:rest="http://basex.org/rest" 
                name="xml" 
                resources="1">
  <rest:resource type="xml" 
                 content-type="application/xml" 
                 size="33739"
    >path/test.xml</rest:resource>
</rest:databases>
```

Queries like `/rest/xml?query=//element` work

But

Queries like `/rest/xml/path?query=//element` do not

Nor do queries like `/rest/xml/path/test.xml?query=//element`

Both return an error:

```
[BXDB0005] Query must yield database nodes.
```

What am I misunderstanding about the architecture?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious cause of a problem here is that your sample queries

```
/rest/xml/path?query=//element
```

and

```
/rest/xml/path/test.xml?query=//element
```

append the string '/path' to the database name; what is it doing there?  You have shown us you have one document in the database 'xml', named 'test.xml'.  You don't show us any documents name 'path'.  I'd try

```
/rest/xml/text.xml?query=//element
```